# Error using imageMagick's mogrify "delegate failed"

Tags: 16.04, imagemagick

I am trying to convert an image file from `jpg` to `png` but returns an error.

```
mogrify -format png abc.jpg
mogrify: delegate failed `"dwebp" -pam "%i" -o "%o"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1310.
mogrify: unable to open image `/tmp/magick-...': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.
mogrify: unable to open file  `/tmp/magick-...': No such file or directory @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/540.
```

Comment: That command works for me (in Lubuntu 18.04 LTS). It creates a corresponding file `abc.png` (instead of overwriting the jpg file). Which version and flavour of Ubuntu are you running? How did you install imagemagick? Is the file `abc.jpg` available and healthy?

Answer (score 9):

The error message suggests that your input file isn't a [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) but a [WebP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP) file.

To handle WebP files ImageMagick needs the program `dwebp` from the package `webp`. Install that package, for example by using

```
sudo apt-get install webp
```